# Can not pass variable from jquery to php

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post, jquery-ajax

I want to pass a variable from jquery to PHP on the same page (I am using WordPress).

I tried using using ajax post like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("li.year-item a").click(function(){
            $post = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type  : "POST",
                url: "https://example.com/exhibition/",
                data: {yearValue: $($post).attr("value")},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

and I get the post variable below the script tag:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST['yearValue']); ?>
```

but the var_dump result is null..

I have no idea.. anyone can help me? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wordpress you should use the built in [Ajax mechanism](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

```
$.ajax({
    type  : "POST",
    url: "https://your-site.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: {
        action: 'retrieve_yearvalue', 
        yearValue: $($post).attr("value"),
        test: 'Test is ok'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

On PHP-Side:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_retrieve_yearvalue', 'my_year_retrieve_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_retrieve_yearvalue', 'my_year_retrieve_function' );

function my_year_retrieve_function() {
    $yearValue = $_REQUEST['yearValue'];
    $test = $_REQUEST['test'];
    
    $response = array(
        'recieved_year' => $yearValue,
        'test_data' => $test
    );
    
    wp_send_json( $response );
}
```